# Prove theorem of Existence and Uniqueness of solutions of a $n$-th order differential equation using Picard-Lindelöf theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my textbook, after stating and proving the Picard-Lindelöf theorem, the following corollary is stated:

> **Corollary.** Let $f:[t_0,t_1]\times\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous and Lipschitz function with respect to its second variable in its domain. Then, for all $\overline\xi=(\xi_0, \xi_1, ..., \xi_{n-1})\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and for all $t^*\in[t_0, t_1]$, the following Cauchy problem has a unique solution $x(t)$ defined in $[t_0, t_1]$ and of class $C^1$:
>   $$\left \{
>       \begin{matrix} 
>          x^{(n)}(t)=f(t,x(t),x'(t),...,x^{(n-1)}(t)), \forall t \in [t_0, t_1]\\
>          x(t^*)=\xi_0, x'(t^*)=\xi_1, ..., x^{(n-1)}(t^*)=\xi_{n-1}
>       \end{matrix}
>    \right .$$

How can I prove this corollary using Picard-Lindelöf theorem?

Comment: I think that you state the question slightly wrong: what you've asked is to prove that a solution has certain class of smoothness (that's what phrase "...and of class $C^n$" is about). But then you have to say something about smoothness of $f$.

Comment: As it is mentioned above the statement, as given, is incorrect. If you change your "a unique solution $x(t)$ defined in $[t_0,t_1]$ and of class $C^n$" for "a unique solution $x(t)$ defined in $[t^\ast-\delta,t^\ast+\delta]$ and of class $C^1$", then the proof follows from the fact the any $n$-th order equation can be written as a system of $n$ first order equations.